# How do I check in AWS Config query whether particular key exists or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

Down below is my original query to check `non_compliance` for `codebuild-project-s3-logs-encrypted`

It returning 0 results. Well, I observed for some buckets, key `s3Logs` only not there, so that would be default, `non_compliant`. same with `encryptionDisabled` key.

```
SELECT
  resourceId,
  accountId,
  resourceType,
  configuration.logsConfig.s3Logs.encryptionDisabled,
  configuration.encryptionKey,
  tags
WHERE
  resourceType = 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project'
  AND configuration.logsConfig.s3Logs.encryptionDisabled = 'true'
```